# how to use class, objects and methods

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build a calculator that will give me the calculation for width *length and Area and perimeter. Now where I'm stuck, once I label the text box ( txtWidth) and then I click on it to bring up the code editor what do I put in under the handler. Second question how do I enter the math for them. Like I know that to get the area I just do width*length and for perimeter it's 2*width + 2*length. And I also need to add fractional decimal entries like 10.5 and 20.65. I hope this gives more insight to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is this still an active question?  This sounds easy, but I think we might need some more background here.  Are you building a webpage (browser-based application) or a windows dialog?  what language are you using?

Comment: please close out this question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using C#... add two labels (lblArea & lblPerimeter) and a button (btnCalculate), and add an event for the button (double-click on it):

Here's your homework:

```
        private void CalculateDisplayInfo()
        {
            double len = 0.0;
            if (!double.TryParse(txtLength.Text, out len))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Length Input", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return;
            }

            double width = 0.0;
            if (!double.TryParse(txtWidth.Text, out width))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Width Input", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return;
            }

            lblArea.Text = (width * len).ToString();
            lblPerimeter.Text = (2 * (width + len)).ToString();
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateDisplayInfo();
        }
```